# Why can't cron access a CIFS share using Kerberos authentication?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, kerberos, cifs

I'm on CentOS 6.4.  Using kstart I have a TGT kept active using the machine account (ie computername$) from Active Directory.  The ticket cache is assigned to root and is located at /tmp/krb5cc_0.  I mount.cifs as root using sec=krb5.  This works and I can browse the share.

The problem is that while a user can browse the share fine via ssh, rsync running under cron can't access it after its already been mounted.  Nor can the Subversion Edge backup function.  Rsync gets error:

```
rsync: ERROR: cannot stat destination "/mnt/dfs/backups/redmine/": Key has been revoked (128)
```

and csvn's backup gets the same 128 error:

```
CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -128
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -128
```

and sometimes a

```
CIFS VFS: Send error in SessSetup = -122
CIFS VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -122
```

which I think means no quota.

I've tried disabling SELinux, so that's not the issue.  How can I get these "background tasks" to be able to use a Kerberos CIFS share?

Comment: Does it work if you manually mount it and run the rsync job yourself as root (so it's not a time out issue)? Someone here http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.cifs/8592 had the same issue, it looks like the kerberos tickets are not renewing or being used properly by cifs.upcall

Comment: Yes, it works if I manually mount it.  I think I'm having a different issue.  For me the automatic TGT retrieval that cifs.upcall supposedly does has never worked so I use kstart to keep my root TGT active.

Answer (score 1):

Cron isn't using the ticket cache, either because it doesn't know to (`KRB5CCNAME` isn't set or passed to the job) or it can't read the cache (permissions on the cache prevent the user the job is running as from reading it).

Comment: This was a good idea, and I tried exporting KRB5CCNAME=/tmp/krb5cc_0 in the cron job, but it doesn't look like that is the issue.  I'm not using a multiuser mount, so I don't think it matters what credentials the user doing the access has.  I'm using autofs to mount it and the user and group are set to root.